# How to implement blocking queue-like SQL mechanism

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

My programme is a notification service, it basically receives http requests(client sends notifications) and forwards them to a device.

I want it to work the following way:

1. receive client notification request
2. save it to the database(yes, i need this step, its mandatory)
3. async threads watch new requests in database
4. async threads forward them to the destination(device).

In this case the programme can send client confirmation straight away after the step 2).
Thus, not waiting for the destination to respond(device response time can be too long).

If I stored client notification in memory i would use BlockingQueue. But I need to persist my notifications in db. Also, I cannot use Message Queues, because clients want rest endpoints to send notifications.

Help me to work out the architecture of such a mechanism.

PS In Java, Postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas that can lead to the solution:

1. Probably the step 2 is mandatory to make sure that the request is persisted so that rather it will be queried. So we're talking about some "data model" here.
   With this in mind, if you "send" the confirmation "right away after the step 2" - what if later you want to do some action with this data (say, send it somewhere) and this action doesn't succeed. You store it on disk? what happens if the disk is full?

The most important question is what happens to your data model (in the database) in this case? Should the entry in the database still be there or the whole "logical" action has failed? This is something you should figure out depending on the actual system the answers can be different.

The most "strict" solution would use transactions in the following (schematic) way:

```
tr = openTransaction()
try {
   saveRequestIntoDB(data);
   forwardToDestination(data);
   tr.commit();
} catch(SomeException ex) {
   tr.rollback();
}
```

With this design, if something goes wrong during the "saveRequest" step - well, nothing will happen. If the data is stored in db, but then `forwardToDestination` fails - then the transaction will be rolled back and the record won't be stored in DB.

If all the operations succeed - the transaction will be committed.

2. Now It looks like you still can use the messaging system in step 4. Sending message can be fast and won't add any significant overhead to the whole request.

On the other hand, the benefits are obvious:
- Who listens to these "notifications"? If you send something and only one service should receive and process the notification how do you make sure that others won't get it? How would you implement the opposite - what if all the services should get the notification and process it independently?

These facilities are already implemented by any descent messaging system.

3. I can't really understand the statement:

> I cannot use Message Queues, because clients want rest endpoints to send notifications.

Since the whole flow is originated by the client's request I don't see any contradication here. The code that is called from rest endpoint (which is after all is a logic entrypoint that should be implemented by you) can call the database, persist the data and then send the notification...

Comment: 1. I save requests to the db to ensure resilience: Client send the notification request, and the service answers him : "Your notification will be ultimately forwarded to the device, even in case of any possible failure." SO the client is sure, the notification some time later will pop up in device.

Comment: 2. Lets state that only one device is listen to notifications

Comment: 3. Client sends notification request to Notification service via rest, then Notifications service forwards them to the device via rest. (No Message queues in this flow, as you can see)